# setListItemChecked not highlighting all of the list items

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, sectionindexer

## Situation

I have a muliple choice mode ListView with two view types- normal and header. I load the data from the contacts app by retrieving a cursor with the names and emails and make use of the AlphabetIndexer class. My adapter extends the SimpleCursorAdapter class and implements the SectionIndexer. Moreover I override the getCount() method of my adapter so that it returns the count of the cursor + the count of the sections. In addition, my layouts are correct and items highlight in the onListItemClickListener, according to the user actions.

## Problem

However, I want to highlight all the items with a Check All Button but the code fails to do that.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= adapter.getCount() - 1; i++) {
            adapter.getItem(i);
            if (adapter.getItemViewType(i) == InviteContactListAdapter.TYPE_NORMAL) {
                listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }

        }
```

It changes correctly the layout of the items with position smaller than the cursror.getCount() and then refuses to mark the rest with a bigger index.I log the ListView.getCheckedItemPositions()
and this list includes all the items, including the ones whose layout has not been checked.

```
Log.d("checkedItems:", listView.getCheckedItemPositions()):
```

So their state is changed but not their layout.

## Example

I have a list with 55 contacts and 20 section headers. When i run the Select All Button items with position 0... 55 get highlighted. Items from 56 to 75 get only get checked, not highlighted.

## Code

```
public class InviteContactListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements
    SectionIndexer {

public static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
public static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 0;
public static final int TYPE_COUNT = 2;

private AlphabetIndexer indexer;

private int[] usedSectionNumbers;
private Map<Integer, Integer> sectionToPosition;
private Context context;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> sectionToOffset;

public InviteContactListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, 0);

    ArrayList<String> stringCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
    Character firstLetter;
    String firstLetterAsString;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        firstLetter = c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
                .charAt(0);
        firstLetter = Character.toUpperCase(firstLetter);
        firstLetterAsString = firstLetter.toString();
        if (!stringCollection.contains(firstLetterAsString)
                && Character.isLetter(firstLetter)) {
            stringCollection.add(firstLetterAsString);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(stringCollection);
    String alphabet = " ";
    for (String s : stringCollection) {
        alphabet = alphabet + s;
    }
    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("length", "" + alphabet.length());

    this.context = context;
    indexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c,
            c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME),
            alphabet);
    sectionToPosition = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    sectionToOffset = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    final int count = super.getCount();

    int i;
    for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sectionToPosition.put(indexer.getSectionForPosition(i), i);
    }

    i = 0;
    usedSectionNumbers = new int[sectionToPosition.keySet().size()];

    for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()) {
        sectionToOffset.put(section, i);
        usedSectionNumbers[i] = section;
        i++;
    }

    for (Integer section : sectionToPosition.keySet()) {
        sectionToPosition.put(section, sectionToPosition.get(section)
                + sectionToOffset.get(section));
    }
    Log.d("", "");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (super.getCount() != 0) {
        return super.getCount() + usedSectionNumbers.length;
    }

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL) {
        return super.getItem(position
                - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    if (!sectionToOffset.containsKey(section)) {
        int i = 0;
        int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;

        while (i < maxLength && section > usedSectionNumbers[i]) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i == maxLength)
            return getCount();

        return indexer.getPositionForSection(usedSectionNumbers[i])
                + sectionToOffset.get(usedSectionNumbers[i]);
    }
    return indexer.getPositionForSection(section)
            + sectionToOffset.get(section);
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    int i = 0;
    int maxLength = usedSectionNumbers.length;
    while (i < maxLength
            && position >= sectionToPosition.get(usedSectionNumbers[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    return usedSectionNumbers[i - 1];
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    return indexer.getSections();
}

// nothing much to this: headers have positions that the sectionIndexer
// manages.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == getPositionForSection(getSectionForPosition(position))) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    }
    return TYPE_NORMAL;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_COUNT;
}

// return the header view, if it's in a section header position
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int type = getItemViewType(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (type == TYPE_HEADER) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_alphabet_section_header, parent,
                    false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.letter_header))
                .setText((String) getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);

        return convertView;
    }
    return super.getView(
            position - sectionToOffset.get(getSectionForPosition(position))
                    - 1, convertView, parent);
}

// these two methods just disable the headers
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_HEADER) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

I think the issue might be that you are calling the `super` methods all over the place, which in my opinion means that the default behavior of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` has (which includes highlighting a selection) only applies to the first `size of the cursor` items.

In other words, **highlighting a selected row** is not a **default** "feature" of an `Adapter`, but rather something you must implement explicitly.

While the `SimpleCursorAdapter` **has** the highlighting "built-in", it only does so for a number of items equal to the `Cursor`'s size.

I don't see how you can change this, other than managing the views yourself manually in the `getView` method (i.e. do the highlighting yourself by changing the background of the views).

Comment: Thank you Bogdan, but that is not the case. I triple checked it and it is absolutely correct. I think somewhere in the base classes the code uses the cursor's count not the adapter's. However, I cannot find it.

Comment: @dTod I have reviewed my opinion on this, I hope it helps now :)